# linking mongoDB to python code?

Tags: python, mongodb, bots, telegram

still very new to programming so in my quest to learn git i am working on getting a chat bot for telegram up and running that i found on a github. iv never used mongoDB or any database and i see i need

```
DB_NAME=os.environ['DB_NAME']
DB_USERNAME=os.environ['DB_USERNAME']
DB_HOST=os.environ['DB_HOST']
DB_PASSWORD=os.environ['DB_PASSWORD']
DB_URL="dbname='"+DB_NAME+"' user='"+DB_USERNAME+"' host='"+DB_HOST+"' password='"+DB_PASSWORD+"'"

conn=psycopg2.connect(DB_URL)
cur=conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT chat_id FROM users")
users=cur.fetchall()
id_list=[chat_id[0] for chat_id in users]
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

the DB_NAME=os.environ['DB_NAME']
where does DB_NAME come from and why does os.environ throw an error. im using python 3. the github is here https://github.com/trinhvv/trading-analysis-bot

Comment: `os` is a standard library module. The `os` module's `environ` attribute is essentially (albeit not exactly) a dictionary. The keys of the `environ` dictionary are your environment variable names and the values of the dictionary are the corresponding environment variable values. You can set these a number of ways. One of which is to run (from your bash shell) a command like `export DB_NAME=whatever_your_db_name_is`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

os.environ["DB_NAME"] means that DB_NAME is stored in the system environment variables.

You can connect to the mongodb by:

**Option 1:**

Declare variables in system environment.

**Option 2:**

declaring enviornment variables in the code itself.
Environment variables must be strings, so use,

`os.environ["DB_NAME"] = "your_db_name"`

**Option 3:**

Don't use variables from environment, write it directly,

`DB_NAME = "your_db_name"`